# How to Change Configuration Class Property for Single Test Class in Visual Studio with WebDriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I am working on developing automated tests in Visual Studio with Selenium Webdriver for a web portal application. My current issue is that some tests are failing in one browser but not another.

I believe the failed tests are a result of the pages taking significantly longer in one browser than the other. I want to adjust my timeout settings for these tests in this browser without changing the timeout settings for the other browser for the same test, but I'm not sure how.

I have a helper class, Configuration, that stores constants such as my default timeout values.

```
       public static TimeSpan TimeoutForLocalChange { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

       public static TimeSpan TimeoutForPageLoad { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

A Pages folder contains classes for each page as well as a base page class for common aspects of the site pages. My default WebDriverWaits are defined in the base page class.

```
public PageBase(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        this.WebDriver = webDriver;
        this.WaitForDom = new WebDriverWait(this.WebDriver, Configuration.TimeoutForLocalChange);
        this.WaitForAjax = new WebDriverWait(this.WebDriver, Configuration.TimeoutForPageLoad);
    }

public WebDriverWait WaitForDom { get; }
public WebDriverWait WaitForAjax { get; }
```

The Tests folder contains tests for each area of the site, with the tests written in an Abstract class that is browser agnostic. A separate class for each browser is used to actually run the tests.

I am not sure how to best adjust my WebDriverWaits for only one browser. This is probably a pretty basic thing but so far I haven't been able to turn up applicable instructions/examples that work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I wouldn't change it for just one browser, I would change the default for all. The timeout is just the longest amount of time that Selenium will wait until some condition is true. For example, if a page takes 3 seconds to load in Chrome but 10 seconds to load in IE and you set the timeout to 15 seconds, the page will still take only 3 seconds to load in Chrome and 10 in IE. It doesn't make the test any slower. Now, if one day the test in Chrome takes 10 seconds, it won't timeout if the change is global where it would if it was IE specific.

Also, 1s is a *really* short period of time to wait. I would make it a few seconds at least. I generally use about 10s for pages to load. Remember, it's not going to take 10s... if it's loaded in 500ms, the script will proceed. This is only the longest period of time a script will wait.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - that's a good point, that in general it shouldn't make the successful tests run longer.  
  
I was curious though, as much for a learning thing as anything, should I want to change the timeouts for some tests (or another similar configuration element), do you have suggestions for how to achieve that?

Comment: I use the page object model and I currently just have the wait timeout for each page set uniquely for each page. I have wondered at times whether I should have say a `slowPageLoadTimeout` and a `fastPageLoadTimeout` global and use them so that I can change them all at once but I haven't really found the need to do so. I guess I settled in on 10s as a good timeout for the majority of pages and I have a couple that are slower loading so they are a little higher. If I were going to do something like this, I would create some global `int` variables and store the timeout in seconds.

Comment: Then use them in `WebDriverWait` declarations, as needed. I don't think I would take the approach of creating a global `WebDriverWait` variable, etc. Not that it's bad, it just seems "heavy". Actually, if you put this stuff in your basepage class, it will get instantiated with each page... meaning you will have multiple copies of each variable. I think that's why I would put them as `int`s in some `static` Utils or something class.